# html object not displaying where it should on mobiles devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I'm working on a Flappy bird clone that works as well on mobile devices using service workers. I'm also learning new stuff about these techonologies.

Everything seemed to be working fine on desktop, but on mobile, the bottom pipes display a little higher than they should.

[image: View on my phone]

[image: View on mobile format from desktop]
I'm using this meta viewport configuration:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> FLAPWAPP </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="gamecanvas">
            <div id="sky"></div>
            <div id="playspace">
                <div id="skylimit"></div>
                <div id="bird" class="bird"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="land"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                navigator.serviceWorker
                    .register('sw.js')
                    .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
            }
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.pipe 
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 52px;
    left: -100px;
    animation: pipeAnimation 7500ms linear;
}

.pipe_upper
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    width: 52px;
    background-image: url('../assets/pipe.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
}

.pipe_upper:after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 52px;
    height: 26px;
    background-image: url('../assets/pipe-down.png');
}

.pipe_lower
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 52px;
    background-image: url('../assets/pipe.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: center;
}

.pipe_lower:after
{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 52px;
    height: 26px;
    background-image: url('../assets/pipe-up.png');
}
```

What this could be? You can check the entire source code on my github: [github](https://github.com/llucmk/FLAPWAPP)

Comment: Add some code to get help.

Comment: Yep, sorry. I added my github code because I can't get the source of it... I also misspressed enter and it published before I could add the link. Sorry about that

Comment: edit the question and add the code. It's simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved here: https://github.com/llucmk/FLAPWAPP/blob/master/js/main.js

There was a problem related to the javascript and the object position, not giving it's correct position with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because android is base on linux. So some of your css code might has being ignored by the android. Find the code, and use the webkit on it.